# How to access methods of decorator class?

Tags: c++, decorator

I have the following program that implements a basic decorator class, but the decorators also have there own member functions that i would like to be accessible. in the example below, i would like to do something like finalMouse->rightMouseButton->click(). Can this type of interaction even be done with a decorator, or is it another design pattern? I was thinking maybe strategy, but that doesn't seem applicable.

Thanks

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef enum _location { TOP, SIDE } location;
typedef enum _direction { FORWARD, BACKWARD } direction;

class MouseAbstract
{
    public:
        virtual string printConfiguration() = 0;
};

class Mouse : public MouseAbstract
{
    public:
        Mouse(string n) { name = n; };
        string printConfiguration() {
            return name + " Configuration: ";
        }
    private:
        string name;
};

class MouseConfigurationAddon : public MouseAbstract
{
    public:
        MouseConfigurationAddon(MouseAbstract* add, location loc, string desc) {
            addon = add;
            mLocation = loc;
            description = desc;
        };
        string printConfiguration() {
            string outLoc = (mLocation == TOP) ? "Location: Top" : "Location: Side";
            return addon->printConfiguration() + "\n\nAddon: " + description + ", " + outLoc;
        }
    protected:
        MouseAbstract* addon;
        location mLocation;
        string description;
};

class Button : public MouseConfigurationAddon
{
    public:
        Button(MouseAbstract* add, location loc, string desc) : MouseConfigurationAddon(add, loc, desc) {};
        string click() {
            return description + " has been clicked.";
        };
};

class ScrollWheel : public MouseConfigurationAddon
{
public:
    ScrollWheel(MouseAbstract* add, location loc, string desc) : MouseConfigurationAddon(add, loc, desc) {};
    string spin(direction dir, double rotations) {
        string outDir = (mLocation == FORWARD) ? "forward" : "backward";
        return description + " has been spun " + outDir + to_string(rotations) + " rotations.";
    };
};

int main() {
    Mouse* baseMouse = new Mouse("My Gaming Mouse");
    Button* rightMouseButton = new Button(baseMouse, TOP, "Right Mouse Button");
    Button* leftMouseButton = new Button(rightMouseButton, TOP, "Left Mouse Button");
    Button* sideButton1 = new Button(leftMouseButton, SIDE, "Side Button 1");
    Button* sideButton2 = new Button(sideButton1, SIDE, "Side Button 2");
    ScrollWheel* finalMouse = new ScrollWheel(sideButton2, TOP, "Scroll Wheel");

    cout << finalMouse->printConfiguration() << endl;

    delete finalMouse;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No design pattern will make `finalMouse->rightMouseButton->click()` work, at least not if you don't make `rightMouseButton` a member of the `Scrollwheel` class. Adding data members dynamically to a class based on the decorators you instantiate would require runtime reflection, but C++ doesn't even have compile-time reflection yet. If you don't need to create configurations at runtime you might get something similar to work using CRTP. Anyway, what is wrong with just calling `rightMouseButton->click()`?  After all you already have the `rightMouseButton` variable.

Comment: This is not Java. Do not use naked `new` like that. It is a terrible practice. Write `Mouse baseMouse{"My Gaming Mouse"}` or `auto baseMouse = Mouse{"My Gaming Mouse"}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Corristo. I learned some interesting things and you confirmed my initial thought. There is nothing wrong with calling rightMouseButton->click() but it would have been semantically nice to call it as part of the hierarchy for readability purposes, but since it can not be done then this will work fine